# Models are not being loaded/accessed in engine tasks from engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-engines, ruby-on-rails-4.2

Accessing engine models in engine rake tasks are throwing `NameError: uninitialized constant`. Models are namespaced and correctly defined. Can be accessed from rails console of mounted application

But not from engine rake tasks

Answer (score 5):

If you require the Rails application to be mounted, try to add the `environment` dependency to your task. As an example:

```
namespace :foo do
  desc 'Super awesome task'
  task super_awesome: [:environment] do
    # etc
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Including `=> :environment` will tell Rake to load full the application environment, giving the relevant task access to things like classes, helpers, models, etc. Without the `:environment`, you won't have access to any of those extras.